# linq to extract specific subset

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

Given a directory of files (as a FileInfo array) how would I go about extracting all the filenames that have a corresponding filename with a specific extension.

For example, given a directory of the following files;

```
file1.txt
file1.txt.xml
file2.txt
file2.txt.xml
file3.xml
file3.xml.xml
```

How would I extract file1.txt, file2.txt and file3.xml. Basically, I am looking for any file that has a correspoding entry with my given extension (xml in this case).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will produce a list of the corresponding files (assuming that files is an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>`:

```
var ext = ".xml"; // To match your example above
var list = files.Where(f => f.Extension.Equals(ext, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                .Select( f => Path.Combine(f.DirectoryName, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name)))
                .Where( n => File.Exists(n))
                .ToList();
```

Comment: This works a treat. Thanks. I was almost there, but I just couldn't quite get it worked out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

James's solution works.  You can also use

```
files.Where(fi => fi.Extension == ext).ToList();
```

Comment: D'oh!  I checked (sorta) and didn't find a Extension property (I just looked at the FileInfo specific properties listed in the Contents panel in the Help Viewer.  I didn't think that an Extension property might be inherit from a base class)

Answer (score 1):

You could go with something like

```
string path = @"C:\Temp\XYZ";
string mainExtension = ".txt"; // optionally use
string companionExtension = ".xml";

var mainFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path); // or (path, "*" + mainExtension); 
var companionFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + companionExtension);

var filesWithCompanions = from file in mainFiles
                            from companion in companionFiles
                            where companion == file + companionExtension
                            select file;
```

If the directory is rather large, something like the below may be more optimal

```
var companionQuery = companionFiles.Select(file => file.Replace(Path.GetExtension(file), ""));
var companionSet = new HashSet<string>(companionQuery);
var filesWithCompanions = mainFiles.Where(companionSet.Contains);
```

Comment: I like this better. This is closer to what I need. The thing is, I don't know exactly what extension the main set of files will have. I can only know that if there are two files with the same name and one has my extension, then that is the one I am interested in. I am messing about with Enumerable.Contains method to look for files where file.Name.Contains(file.Name + "myknownextension"), but I'm not sure if I can create some anonymous comparator or something, or if I have to create an entire new comparator class for this.

Comment: @Mr Moose, you can omit the `mainExtension` portion and simply use the single variable `path` overload on the `var mainFiles = ...` line. The code should still logically work. I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ext = ".xml";
FileInfo[] files = ...
var filered = files.Where(fi=> fi.Name.EndsWith(ext)).ToList();
// filtered is an List<FileInfo>
```

However, you probably don't need the ToList() (or the filters variable)

```
var ext = ".xml";
FileInfo[] files = ...
foreach(var file in files.Where(fi=> fi.Name.EndsWith(ext))
{ 
     // do something with "file" here
}
```

Comment: Thanks James. I could get this far, however, I am looking for something a little more dynamic. For example, basically, I need every filename that has a matching filename plus my extension (which in this case just happens to be xml).